# CakePHP autentication with auth table other than User problem

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i have lots of problems with development of cakephp authentication. for that purpose i'm trying to use table named `reviewers`, that contains fields username and password, of course.

i checked, and from login form proper data is sent (username and password).

file app_controller.php contains:

```
    class AppController extends Controller {
var $components = array('Auth', 'Session', 'Cookie', 'P28n');

    function beforeFilter() {

        $this->Auth->authenticate = ClassRegistry::init('Reviewer');

        Security::setHash('sha1'); // or sha1 or sha256
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Reviewers';
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password'=>'password');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'reviewers', 'action' => 'view');

    }
```

how can i check and debug problem? error i get is that username and password combination is not correct.

what drives me mad is that i have alredy developed simular functionality before and it worked without problems........

pls help.

UPDATE: with cakephp debuggint tool, it looks like auth component is never called.

Comment: Are you overwriting your beforeFilter() function in a controller somewhere?

Make sure to call parent::beforeFilter();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problem with Cake 1.3, It appears that the Auth Component's auto hashing differs from hashing that is made when you save your users.

I ended up with this solution:
I've added this in users controller before save.

```
$this->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['User']['password']);
```

and now it works fine... maybe this will help.

Comment: nope, still the same. but, confuses me that i can not see sql query in sql dump that creates cakephp if debug is turned on. so, for me it looks like auth controller is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try `$this->Auth->authenticate =& ClassRegistry::init('Reviewer')` to get a reference to the object.

[AuthComponent - authenticate Property](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/auth-component)